# Why 'null' is returned while using 'style' as a parameter in getAttribute() in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Why 'null' is returned while using 'style' as a parameter in getAttribute() in Selenium?
This is my code:

**WebElement buttonColor= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="j_idt88:j_idt100"]/span"));
String color= buttonColor.getAttribute("style");**

The solution is to use getCssValue() but I want to know the reason why getAttribute() doesn't work.